# Fixing drifting Google Sheets Apps Script image buttons

Tags: image, google-sheets, button

I am looking for a reliable resource instead of only a GPT hallucination...

I am trying to get my Google Sheets buttons to stay in one place when I load the sheet. they tend to drift around or move out of the original location while the page is loading the dataframe. I figure it may be partly due to the margins and cell locations resizing the window, but I've tried putting it inside a cell, this is one of GPT's hallucinations.

What can I do to get the button to stay in one place, always, when I load it.

Comment: It maybe depends of what you're calling "Button". I used to use a drawing and assign a macro to it and this works fine for me as button, it stays in place anyway.

Could you share us a sample of your issue?